# fullpage.js - adding links within tooltips

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullpage.js

**PROBLEM**

I've tried adding a link to the navigational tooltips and, based on html, it should be working. However, no matter which tooltip I click, I am taken to the second section - even though the address indicated is correct and should be taking me across all sections.

```
for (var i = 0; i < $(SECTION_SEL).length; i++) {
            var link = '';
            if (options.anchors.length) {
                link = options.anchors[i];
            }

            var li = '<li><a href="#' + link + '"><span></span></a>';

            // Only add tooltip if needed (defined by user)
            var tooltip = options.navigationTooltips[i];

            if (typeof tooltip !== 'undefined' && tooltip !== '') {
                li += '<div class="' + SECTION_NAV_TOOLTIP + ' ' + options.navigationPosition + '">' + '<a href="#' + link + '">' + tooltip + '</a></div>';
            }

            li += '</li>';

            nav.find('ul').append(li);
        }
```

I've tried putting the links into the init file as well, but that has the exact same effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fullpage.js will ignore your link.
See [line 1694](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/blob/master/jquery.fullPage.js#L1694)

```
    function sectionBulletHandler(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var index = $(this).parent().index();
        scrollPage($(SECTION_SEL).eq(index));
    }
```

And [line 567](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/blob/master/jquery.fullPage.js#L567):

```
.on('click touchstart', SECTION_NAV_SEL + ' a', sectionBulletHandler)
```